# Flutter does not render my app when i change screen size

Tags: flutter

Im trying to make a responsive screen size for my app.

I close the android emulator and opened chrome.The thing is when i try to change the dimensions some times flutter does not render the entire container it leaves white spaces like here : [image]

my code is like this :

```
class LogIn extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = Provider.of<DeviceDimensions>(context).screenWidth;
    final height = Provider.of<DeviceDimensions>(context).screenHeight;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: ContainerStyles.gradientBoxDecoration,
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,....
```

I take my dimensions from  my provider , hre is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DeviceDimensions with ChangeNotifier {
  late double _screenWidth;
  late double _screenHeight;

  DeviceDimensions(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _screenWidth = mediaQuery.size.width;
    _screenHeight = mediaQuery.size.height;
  }

  // Define getters for width and height
  double get screenWidth => _screenWidth;
  double get screenHeight => _screenHeight;

  void _updateDimensions(BuildContext context) {
    final mediaQuery = MediaQuery.of(context);
    _screenWidth = mediaQuery.size.width;
    _screenHeight = mediaQuery.size.height;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

How i can fix that ?

I **change my var types** also but nothing .

Thank you for your time.